# Linux rename files to uppercase

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have large number of files in the format `x00000.jpg`, `X00000.jpg` and `xx00000.jpg`.

How can I rename these files so they are all uppercase, ignoring the numeric part of the name?

Comment: Do you want the renamed `x00000.jpg` to replace the original `X00000.jpg`?

Comment: Linux tends to like lowercase file names. Why do you want everything in uppercase?

Comment: honestly, it was either upper or lower and I picked upper at random. I'm using the images as part of a url, which I'm linking to from an ID provided in a data feed. the ID matches the image name. Unfortunatly, the feed data and image file data don't match up case-wise.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
for f in * ; do mv -- "$f" "$(tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< "$f")" ; done
```

Comment: But why a subshell, a fork and a here-string? `"${f^^}"` would have been enough.

Comment: The arguments to tr should be quoted too. Consider `touch l u; tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< "hello world"`

Comment: Will that not rename `x00000.jpg` to `X00000.JPG` though OP seems to be wanting `X00000.jpg`

Comment: Passing the `-s` option to `tr` looks like a bug to me that can destroy data.

Comment: It should also be noted that `tr [:lower:] [:upper:]` does not (yet) handle multi-byte characters. The same applies to the proposed `${f^^}` in bash (fixed in bash 4.3, which is not released yet). `sed` works, at least on my machine.

Comment: This Solution works also with cygwin. Tried the others below and didn't work properly (added an additional dot after the file extension).

Comment: change `mv` to `echo` for a "dry run".

Answer (score 20):

You can't rename files from Bash only, because Bash doesn't have any built-in command for renaming files. You have to use at least one external command for that.

If Perl is allowed:

```
perl -e 'for(@ARGV){rename$_,uc}' *.jpg
```

If Python is allowed:

```
python -c 'import os, sys; [os.rename(a, a.upper()) for a in sys.argv[1:]]' *.jpg
```

If you have thousands or more files, the solutions above are fast, and the solutions below are noticably slower.

If AWK, `ls` and `mv` are allowed:

```
# Insecure if the filenames contain an apostrophe or newline!
eval "$(ls -- *.jpg | awk '{print"mv -- \x27"$0"\x27 \x27"toupper($0)"\x27"}')"
```

If you have a lots of file, the solutions above don't work, because `*.jpg` expands to a too long argument list (error: *Argument list too long*).

If `tr` and `mv` are allowed, then see damienfrancois' answer.

If `mv` is allowed:

```
for file in *; do mv -- "$file" "${file^^}"; done
```

Please note that these rename `.jpg` to `.JPG` at the end, but you can modify them to avoid that.

Comment: Word of caution, the Perl command will also make the extension upper case so pdf/zip files will become PDF/ZIP

Comment: @ParikTiwari: This is true for all commands in this answer, and also for most commands in other answers as well.

Answer (score 16):

The `bash` shell has a syntax for translating a variable name to all-caps.

```
for file in * ; do      # or *.jpg, or x*.jpg, or whatever
    mv "$file" "${file^^}"
done
```

This feature was introduced in bash version 4.0, so first verify that your version of `bash` implements it. To avoid mistakes, try it once replacing `mv` by `echo mv`, just to make sure it's going to do what you want.

The documentation for this feature is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), or type `info bash` and search for "upper".

You should probably decide what to do if the target file already exists (say, if  both `x00000.jpg` and `X00000.JPG` already exists), unless you're certain it's not an issue. To detect such name collisions, you can try:

```
ls *.txt | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

and look for any lines not starting with `1`.

Comment: This works for me, but I wanted the file extension to also change to all upper case characters.  FYI, I'm still (shamefully) rocking version `4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` of bash...

Comment: @Digger: That's exactly what it does. `${file^^}` treats `$file` as a single string. The extension is just part of the file name. But ask yourself why you want to do this. Linux supports upper, lower, and mixed case, but lower case is conventional.

Answer (score 15):

## `rename`

Probably the easiest way for renaming multiple files is using Perl's [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL). To translate lowercase names to upper, you'd:

```
rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *
```

If the files are also in subdirs you can [use globstar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49917/209677) or `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" -execdir rename "y/a-z/A-Z/" {} +
```

#### References

- [Howto: Linux Rename Multiple Files At a Shell Prompt – nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html)
- [More info about **`y/`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands), translate instead of **s**ubstitute.
- [DistroTube - Tools For Renaming Files In Linux](https://youtu.be/8SMnfgThlbM)

Answer (score 8):

Combining previous answers could yield:

```
for file in * ; do            # or *.jpg, or x*.jpg, or whatever
   basename=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "${file%.*}")
   newname="$basename.${file#*.}"
   mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: this works and doesn't mess up the file extension case, i.e. it stays .jpg not .JPG

Answer (score 3):

Using tr:

```
f="x00000.jpg"
n="${f%.*}"
n=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< "$n")
f="$n.${f#*.}"
echo "$f"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
X00000.jpg
```

Comment: Character classes like `[a-z]` are locale-dependent and using them might create hidden bugs. Also, your solution does not handle multi-byte characters.

Comment: Yes that's a fair point though I didn't see `multi-byte` requirement in OP's question but I edited.

Comment: Multi-byte filenames weren't mentioned by the OP, but most filenames are created by humans, so this should be handled by a solution. That said, unfortunately `tr '[:lower:]' ...` does not handle multi-byte characters as well. This is really bad. :( (Oh, and you better quote `[:lower:]` here, because otherwise the shell might expand it to a filename. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the zsh like me:

```
for f in * ; do mv -- "$f" "${f:u}" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If only renaming files/dirs is all you want, then you can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) :

```
rnm -rs '/./\C/g' -fo -dp -1 *
```

Explanation:

1. `-rs` : replace string. `/./\C/g` replaces all match of `.` (regex) to it's uppercase.
2. `-fo` : file only mode
3. `-dp` : depth of directory (-1 means unlimited).

More examples can be found [here](https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm).

Answer (score 0):

## Rename all source files to uppercase and stage to git

```bash
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIRS=('./src' './Public' './Private')
FILE_EXTENSION="*.php"

for dir in $SOURCE_DIRS; do
    files="$(find "$dir" -name "${FILE_EXTENSION[@]}";)"
    for file in $files; do
        base_name="$(basename $file)";
        new_name=$(sed "s/$base_name/${base_name^}/g" <<< $file)
        git mv $file ${new_name} # or
        # mv $file ${new_name}
    done
done
```