# rename all the files in the current directory whose name conatains upper-case into all lower case

Tags: shell

Iam trying a shell script which will rename all the files in the current directory whose name contains upper-case characters into all lower case. For example, if the directory contains a file whose name is CoUnt.c,     it     should be renamed to count.c.

```
for f in *;
do
if [ -f "$f" ]; then
tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
fi
done
```

but it is not working.
is there is any better solution for this?

Comment: try, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253584/linux-rename-files-to-uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any data into the `tr` program, and you are not capturing any output either.

If you are using `sh`:

```
for f in *[A-Z]*
do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        new_name=$(echo "$f"|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
        mv "$f" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Note the indentation - it makes code easier to read.

If you are using `bash` there is no need to use an external program like `tr`, you can use bash expansion:

```
for f in *[A-Z]*
do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
        new_name=${f,,*}
        mv "$f" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Comment: No cheating with bashisms! `;-)` but I like the limit of filenames containing upper case to begin with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: fair, but I did give a POSIX solution first :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `tr` accepts values from `stdin`. So in order to translate upper to lower in each filename, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *
do
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue
    flc=$(echo "$f" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')         ## form lower-case name
    [ "$f" != "$flc" ] && echo mv "$f" "$flc"
done
```

(note: remove the `echo` before `mv` to actually move the files after you are satisfied with the operation)

Answer (score 2):

Since I am unable to add comment posting here,
Used sed and it works for me

#!/bin/bash

```
for i in *
do
if [ -f $i ]
then
kar=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/.*/ \L&/')
mv "$i" "$kar"
done
```

Comment: You should add double-quotes around all accesses to variables in case the filenames contain spaces, so `"$i"` and `"$kar"`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine.

```
for f in *
do
if [ -f $f ]; then 
    echo "$f" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' >/dev/null
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `rename` because it is simple, efficient and also will check for clashes when two different files resolve to the same result:

You can use it with a Perl regex:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Documentation and examples available [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm).

Comment: `rename(1)` is specific to Linux, and not all versions support the options you show.

Comment: @cdarke AFAIK, it is a Perl script that runs on Linux, Unix and OS X and Windows if Perl is installed. I believe the second format/syntax I suggested is supported on all those platforms.

Comment: The rename command is written in C.  It is part of the util-linux package and is available from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.  The kernel interface `rename(2)` is the underlying API, and there is a Perl built-in by that name, but this is not it.  I am running on OS X with Perl installed and there is no rename command-line utility.

Comment: I used `brew install rename` and got a Perl script that works.

Comment: Probably more than one.  It is quite simple to do in Perl (and in bash).  If you need specific install instructions, and a specific version, that should be in your post.